# Why is my Quantity Spinner script not working?

Tags: javascript, product-quantity

The script in right below the Quantity Input and Order button

```
<div class="clear" id="dvQty">
  <p class="qty-label">Qty:</p>
  <div class="qty-plus" id="divup">+</div>
  <div class="qty-input">
    <input name="vwquantity" value="1" class="qty-input" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="qty-minus" id="divdown">-</div>
  <div class="add2cart fl"><input value="Add to Cart" class="ys_primary" title="Add to Cart" type="submit"><input name="vwcatalog" value="bodylogic" type="hidden"><input name="vwitem" value="herbal-select-creme-gallon" type="hidden"></div>

</div>
```

js

```
$("#txtQty").numeric();
$("#divup").click(function() {
  var qty = $("#txtQty").val();
  qty++;
  $("#txtQty").val(qty);
});
$("#divdown").click(function() {
  var qty = $("#txtQty").val();
  if(qty > 1) {
    $("#txtQty").val(qty - 1);
  }
});
```

What am I just not seeing?

Comment: Your input doesn't have the id `txtQty` on it.

Answer (score 0):

add `id="txtQty"` to your input because you call `$("#txtQty")`, replace

```
<input name="vwquantity" value="1" class="qty-input" type="text">
```

with

```
<input id="txtQty" name="vwquantity" value="1" class="qty-input" type="text">
```

`.numeric()` is not jQuery built-in function remove it and it seem don't have jQuery, add line below your html body

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, ewwink. Had to make the ID of the input "vwquantity" beause that's what the shopping cart scripts need to see and on this platform, I do not have access to the cart server. I was certain I already had jQuery called in the head tags. So sure I never checked. But you did. I am grateful. Fixing those issues got everything working.